# Working and building a project with multiple developers with specified permission for each one?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017, file-permissions

We are two developer(me and my friend) and working on a MVC ASP.Net project in Visual Studio 2017 with TFS Online(visualstudio.com, TFVC).
All of us have full access to all files for developing and building to view and test.
We want to outsource part of our project to another developers and we don't want to access full permission of project files to new developers.
If we didn't access full permission to all files to new developers, they can't build project to view and test.
Is there a way to access just some files of a project to another developers but they could build project to view and test?

Comment: Are you using TFVC or Git?

Comment: We are using TFVC.

Comment: Any update on this issue, sir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VSTS/TFS grant users the specific set of permissions that are appropriate for certain roles in your organization. Details of permission please refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/permissions#nbspnbspnbsptfvc-object-level).

It's not hard to restrict someone to access some project files. You could just deny the **Read** permission on a folder level when using TFVC source control.

> **Read**
>
> *Can read the contents of a file or folder. If a user has Read permissions for a folder, the user can see the contents of the folder
>   and the properties of the files in it, even if the user does not have
>   permission to open the files.*

If you are using the host agent to build, during the **get source** step. You(=the new developers) are using your own account to pull source from server to build agent. Without the access to some files in the project, you could not pull down the entire project source code. Definitely, you should not be able to run the build as well.

If you are using the private agent to build, it's able to use network service account as the build service account and queue build. Just give the build service account appropriately permission, you should be able to pull down all source files in the project and run the build. However, since you have denied the access of some other files in the project, it's also not able to view and test them .

In this case, as a workaround, suggest you create an apart branch with your main develop branch, just put some files which your new developers need to work with in this branch. And deny their access to your main branch, When their work have done, they could build/test on the new branch.

Once everything is fine, they could merge changes from the new branch to your main branch. You could then also build/test the entire project in the main branch again.

With this kind of architecture, it's more easy to manage both permissions and team work.